# How can use regex to validate iSCSI target names?

Tags: regex, perl, iscsi

I am trying to craft a regexp to validate iSCSI qualified names. An example of a qualified name is `iqn.2011-08.com.example:storage` This is example is minimal, I have seen other examples that are more extended.

So far what I have to validate off of it this:

```
print "Enter a new target name: ";

my $target_name = <STDIN>;

chomp $target_name;

if ($target_name =~ /^iqn\.\d{4}-\d{2}/xmi) {

    print GREEN . "Target name is valid!" . RESET . "\n";

} else {

    print RED . "Target name is not valid!" . RESET . "\n";

}
```

How can I extend that to work with rest up to the `:` I am not going to parse after the `:` becuase it is a description tag.

Is there a limit to how big a domain name can be?

Comment: Are you asking what the rules are for SCSI names, or how to implement those rules in Perl RegEx?

Comment: @DVK, I am more wondering how implement the rules in Perl RegEx.

Comment: @Solignis, Then why didn't you specify the rules you need help implementing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to RFC3270 (and in turn RFC1035),

```
/
   (?(DEFINE)
      (?<IQN_PAT>
         iqn
         \. 
         [0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}
         \.
         (?&REV_SUBDOMAIN_PAT)
         (?: : .* )?
      )

      (?<EUI_PAT>
         eui
         \.
         [0-9A-Fa-f]{16}
      )

      (?<REV_SUBDOMAIN_PAT>
         (?&LABEL_PAT) (?: \. (?&LABEL_PAT) )*
      )

      (?<LABEL_PAT>
         [A-Za-z] (?: [A-Za-z0-9\-]* [A-Za-z0-9] )?
      )
   )

   ^ (?: (?&IQN_PAT) | (?&EUI_PAT) ) \z
/sx
```

It's not clear if the eui names accept lowercase hex digits or not. I figured it was safer to allow them.

If you condense the above, you get `/^(?:iqn\.[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}(?:\.[A-Za-z](?:[A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9])?)+(?::.*)?|eui\.[0-9A-Fa-f]{16})\z/s`.

(By the way, your use `/m` is wrong, your use of `/i` is wrong, and `\d` can match far more than the allowed `[0-9]`.)

Answer (score 0):

If you only need part before `:` then you can use following regexp:

```
if ($target_name =~ /^iqn\.(\d{4}-\d{2})\.([^:]+):/xmi) {
    my ($date, $reversed_domain_name) = ($1, $2);
```

Regexp `[^:]+` matches to 1 or more non-`:` symbols. It will match even if domain name is not well formed. Further improvements depends on your goal: do you need just get individual components of iSCSI name or do you need to validate its syntax?

---

> Is there a limit to how big a domain name can be?

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System#Domain_name_syntax):

> The full domain name may not exceed a total length of 253

Comment: Mainly I am trying to validate the syntax. I just want to prevent an invalid syntax from being passed.

Comment: what would be an easy way to check for < or = 253 chars after the date but before the :

Comment: @Solignis, Extract it and use `length`. It doesn't gain you anything by testing that, though. One that's 253 chars long is going to be just as wrong as the one that's 254 chars long, even tough it's within the limit.

Comment: @Ivan Nevostruev, the `:` is optional, btw.

Comment: @Solignis, You could use `[^:]{1,253}` instead of `[^:]+`, but then you still have to extract the domain name to see if it's valid. Checking the length will find way fewer problems then checking for allowed characters.